# FXML file inside javafxports project

Tags: android, javafx, javafxports

I'm looking information about javafxports technology and can I use inside this project FXML file.

This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.orden.First'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.0.0'

    // Desktop SQL -> https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc
    desktopRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.11.2'

    embeddedRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-storage-desktop:3.0.0'
    // Embedded SQL -> https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc
    embeddedRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.7.2'

    // Android SQL -> https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid
    androidRuntime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'

    // ios SQL -> https://github.com/robovm/robovm 1.8
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.0.0'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*',
                'SQLite.**.*'
        ]
    }
    embedded {
        remotePlatforms {
            raspberry {
                host = '192.168.1.10'
                username = 'pi'
                password = 'raspberry'
                workingDir = '/home/pi/Gluon'
                jreLocation = '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt'
                execPrefix = 'sudo'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my javaFX first page code:

```
package com.orden;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class First extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            URL url = new File("src/main/java/com/orden/views/MainWindowFXML.fxml").toURL();
            URL url2 = new File("src/main/java/com/orden/views/application.css").toURL();
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(url);


            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(url2.toExternalForm());

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            primaryStage.setTitle("Image saver");
            primaryStage.setResizable(true);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

As we can see I use FXML file to define all my graphical structure (controls etc.). Everything compile ok. I also can create .apk file and run my application on smartfon with Android OS. The problem is when I start application I only see black screen , nothing else.

If someone knows how fix this problem I am open on any tips.
I need solution step by step because gluon plugin configuration is hard.

Below I presents my file tree:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("views/MainWindowFXML.fxml");
URL url2 = getClass().getResource("views/application.css");
```

or

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/com/orden/views/MainWindowFXML.fxml");
URL url2 = getClass().getResource("/com/orden/views/application.css");
```

or

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/orden/views/MainWindowFXML.fxml");
URL url2 = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/orden/views/application.css");
```

Comment: In any cases I see : "java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required." error

Comment: @DawidMalczak Where are those files added? Src or Resources package?  Using gradle, they need to be under the resources package.

Comment: Please click image link on the end of my question. There is my file tree.

Comment: @DawidMalczak So did you try it as José suggested? If you look under the "build" folder, do you see the FXML file in the expected place?

Comment: @DawidMalczak Did you manage to fix this problem? I am having the exact same one.