# FXML Crashes When Compiled to APK

Tags: java, android, gradle, javafx, javafxports

I am trying to make an app with javaFX using javaFXPorts, and this is the last obstacle I have to overcome.

My ./gradlew run runs fine - all of the functionality is there as I would expect it to be. However, when I build the APK and run it on my phone, whenever I try and access the 'Profile' menu, which is the only menu to use fxml files in this new build of my app, the program crashes.

My program also uses CSV files to hold information. I had a similar problem when trying to load them in - I would have my application load it in as soon as it launched, which would lead to a black screen.

However, simply adding a 'raw' subfolder to my resources directory, and updating the CSV file location, fixed this - and this was all despite it working fine on my development machine when I did ./gradlew run. I suspect this is because the APK did not package up the CSV files, so would naturally crash when they tried to access them.

I suspect a similar thing is happening here, in the sense that the APK is not actually packaging the fxml files, and is crashing when trying to access it.

Here is my file directory.

[image: Here is my file directory.]

As you can see, I have the fxml under src/main/resources/scenes/...

And load it into my program using:

```
  private FXMLLoader loader;

  loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/scenes/profile.fxml"));
  loader.setController(this);
  mainPane.setCenter(loader.load());
```

And this works on my development machine.

I found a similar, unanswered, question from 3 years ago:

[FXML file inside javafxports project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626292/fxml-file-inside-javafxports-project)

My build.gradle is as follows:

```
    /*
 * This build file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

 buildscript {
     repositories {
         jcenter()
     }

     dependencies {
         classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.17'
     }
 }

 plugins {
     id 'java'
     id 'application'
     //id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'

 }

apply plugin:'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

 mainClassName = "src.main.java.MainScreen"

 jfxmobile {

 javafxportsVersion = '8.60.12'

 android {
 applicationPackage = 'org.javafxports.ensemble'
  compileSdkVersion = '27'
  androidSdk = 'C:/Users/Luke/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk'

  packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
 }

     ios {
         forceLinkClasses = ['ensemble.**.*']
     }
 }


repositories {
jcenter()
maven {
     url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
 }
 mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is found on compile classpath of this component and consumers.
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.testfx:testfx-junit:4.0.15-alpha'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
      compile "com.opencsv:opencsv:4.0"
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
}

allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}
```

What would be the correct file structure to get the FXML to package? I have tried putting it in the raw folder, and just pushing it up into the main resources folder, but to no avail.

Comment: First of all, "stop guessing/suspecting", and use `adb logcat` to find out the exceptions you get when running your app that cause crashes or black screens. Then see if you can fix them, else post them here.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: You could try this minimal [JavaFX template](https://github.com/meiuwa/javafx-template) as base, and just expand the rest of your code. It includes basic JavaFXPorts configuration for Android and support for [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) stylesheets.